# In Visual Studio 2019, is it possible to remove entries from Intellisense?

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

I previously used VS2010.  Everything worked fine there.  I like my intellisense to automatically accept the top entry when I press space or ;.  This is part of a workflow that has served me well for almost 20 years.

With VS 2019, if I type

```
bool myValue=true;
```

Since I don't by habit capitalize true, Intellisense immediately replaces my line with this:

```
bool myValue=truespeechwaveformat_tag;
```

So... I don't want to kill of Intellisense's behavior-- I just want to say "never, ever, for any reason, suggest truespeechwaveformat_tag" since I have not in my entire career ever used this structure, and will not be starting now.

Is there a way for me to delete that permanently from Intellisense's database?  Or put it on ignore?

Comment: `truespeechwaveformat_tag`is just from the extra library `file mmreg.h` Did you do any extra settings in your project? Or you can try to create a empty project to test it. In my side, when l create a c++ project and then type `bool myValue=true;`, it will not show such abnormal behavior.

Comment: Hi, the only solution i got to work was to dumb down intellisense enough to only offer suggestions for class members.  It's not the optimal solution, but it does at least stop it from autocompletion with crazy esoteric functions and variables.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way for me to delete that permanently from Intellisense's
>   database? Or put it on ignore?

`truespeechwaveformat_tag` seems to be a struct of the file `mmreg.h` which is from the head file `mmreg.h`. In VS2019, the Intellisense is a bit different from VS2010.

You can try these:

**Suggestion**

When you type some letters of **true**, such as `t` and `r`, then the intellisense will lock the **true** entry in the Intellisense, then use **Tab** key rather than **Space** or **Enter**, Intellisense will choose the entry that best matches. And it works well in my side without any trouble.

**In additon**, if you still face this abnormal behavior, i think it could be related to VS extensions or some your extra settings.

**1)** reset your VS settings by `Tools`-->`Import and Export Settings`-->`Reset all the settings`. It will also backup your current settings at the same time and you can 9import it as you want.

**2)** disable any third party extensions by `Extensions`--> `Manage Extensions`-->`Installed.`

**3)** delete the `.vs` hidden folder under the physical path of the solution

Hope it could help you.